# Redirect the page in Android

Tags: android, redirect

I am having two page, in one page am having chronometer, after I left and come back the page the chronometer has stopped, any one can tell me how to redirect the page

My code:

```
            Chronometer chrono=(Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chrono.start();
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "redirect the page", but it sounds as if you should read up on [Android application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). Android activities do not execute when not in foreground. If you want to reset the clock once the activity is again in the foreground, you should probably override [Activity.onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding what you want to do, but it sound like you'd like to start a stop watch of some sort, go to another activity, then come back and check the amount of time passed. If that's your goal, you might be better off storing the start time in a variable, then when the activity is reactivated get the current time, compare to the start time, and compute the time passed.